# PackageKit doesn't seem to be working on kubuntu

Tags: package-management, vala, anjuta

I am having trouble getting the Anjuta IDE working due to it complaining of missing packages and package kit

does anybody know how to fix this? I am using kubuntu 20.10

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to install `gnome-packagekit` package?

Comment: Yes I just installed it as of right now

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem you have to install `gnome-packagekit` package.

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get install gnome-packagekit` and it had the same issue.